# Remove country code from phone number vue-tel-input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using `vue-tel-input`. It is working, but I want to remove the country code from the input field. I have tried using different modes (i.e. `national` and `international`), but it is showing either `+91` or `0`, but I want to remove that `0` or `91` from the field and `input` event.

[image]

```
onInput({ number, isValid, country }) {
  this.mobile=number.significant;
  this.country_code=country.dialCode;
},
```

Comment: does `number.significant` return `09999...`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: If input field contains 0 then number.significant also return 0. I want to remove that 0 or +91 country code from text field in both add or edit case of textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide both the leading `0` and the dial code (`+91`) by disabling the auto formatting. The trade off is this disables all formatting for the number.

```html
<vue-tel-input :autoFormat="false" ... />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hiding-the-dial-code-in-vue-tel-input-i2go6?file=/src/App.vue:28-198)